# Given a 2D array, find combination of columns/rows that reconstruct the input array with minimum error

Tags: python, optimization, combinations, minimization, information-theory

Suppose you have to reproduce each of the values of a 2D array as faithfully as possible, given that your access to the array is indirect. There are 2 senders who can only see 1 dimension of the array (S1 only sees rows and S2 only sees columns) and the receiver has to infer the original input array from the independent information received from both senders. Moreover, S1 and S2 only can't transmitt the exact row/column where each value of the input array falls; instead, they only can transmitt an estimation. For instance, if the input value is in row 2 and column 1; that is, in the index (2,1), S1 can only transmitt 'input value is in row 2 or 3' and, in the same way, S2 can only say 'input value is in columns 0 or 1'. Thus, the receiver has uncertainty about the exact column/row of the array where this value falls. I want to get the combination of signals (groups of column and rows) from which the input array can be reconstructed with minimum error. Let me put an example to clarify it.

Given a 4x4 array and two signals for each dimension (rows and columns), each sender can transmitt 3 different pairs of signals.

```
ar = np.array([[0,0,2,2], [0,0,2,1], [1,2,0,0], [1,1,0,0]])
[[0 0 2 2]
 [0 0 2 1]
 [1 2 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0]]

# possible combinations of signals to transmitt:
poss_comb = [[(0,1), (2,3)], [(0,2), (1,4)], [(0,3), (1,2)]] # each number represents the index of the row/column

# for the first combination of signals, sender 1 would trasnmitt the following to the receiver
signal_1 = poss_comb[0][0] # (0,1)
signal_2 = poss_comb[0][1] # (2,3)

# ar[signal_1] = [[0 0 2 2], [0 0 2 1]]
# ar[signal_2] = [[1 2 0 0], [1 1 0 0]]
```

In this case, all the possible combination of singals that S1 and S2 can transmitt are 9:

```
# pair of signals that S1 and S2 transmitt
S1, S2 = [(0,1), (2,3)], [(0,1), (2,3 ]
S1, S2 = [(0,1), (2,3)], [(0,2), (1,4)]
S1, S2 = [(0,1), (2,3)], [(0,3), (1,2)]
S1, S2 = [(0,2), (1,4)], [(0,1), (2,3)]
S1, S2 = [(0,2), (1,4)], [(0,1), (2,3)]
S1, S2 = [(0,2), (1,4)], [(0,1), (2,3)]
S1, S2 = [(0,3), (1,2)], [(0,1), (2,3)]
S1, S2 = [(0,3), (1,2)], [(0,1), (2,3)]
S1, S2 = [(0,3), (1,2)], [(0,1), (2,3)]
```

Suppose you choose the following combination of signals for rows and columns:

```
Sender1_signals = [(0,1), (2,3)]
Sender2_signals = [(0,1), (2,3)]
```

If the received value is 2 with index (2,1), then S1 will send signal (2,3) which is Sender1_signals[1] and S2 will send signal (0,1), which is Sender2_signals[0]. Since sending these two signals reduce all the 16 possible values of the array to only these four

```
(2,0): 1, (2,1): 2, (3,0): 1, (3,1): 1 # (row,col): value
```

value 2 will be correctly reconstructed ¼ of the times, and ¾ there will be an error of 1. This combination is the best possible one given the constraint. For instance, given the same input value, if the combination of signals is

```
Sender1_signals = [(0,1), (2,3)]
Sender2_signals = [(0,3), (1,2)]
```

The average error for this value will be ¼ + ½ * 2, which is bigger. Therefore, depending on the combinations of signals, the average error reconstruction varies.

Once I calculate all the possible combiantions, I obtain the reconstructed array and the error by calling the following function:

```
def reconstruct_array(matrix, E1, E2): # E1 and E2 are the combination of signals for each sender
    reconstruct = np.zeros(matrix.shape)
    for s1 in E1:
        for s2 in E2:
            values = []
            inter = (get_coord(s1, s2)) # returns all the combinations between coordinates s1 and s2 (intersection in array)
            for pair in inter:
                values.append(matrix[pair])
            mean = np.mean(values)
            for pairs in inter:
                reconstruct[pairs] = mean
    error = np.sum(abs(matrix - rec)) * 1/matrix.size
    
    return error, reconstruct
```

And this is the final output I obtain for the input array above:

```
average error: 0.1875
signals: [[(0, 1), (2, 3)], [(0, 1), (2, 3)]] # combination of signals for each sender with less error
reconstruction: # receiver's reconstruction of the original array based on the signals sent by each sender
 [[0.   0.   1.25 1.25]
 [0.   0.   1.25 1.25]
 [1.25 1.25 0.   0.  ]
 [1.25 1.25 0.   0.  ]]
```

In order to obtain the combination of signals that minimize the error reconstruction of the array I have calculated the error for every possible combination of signals in each dimension, and then choose the combination that returns the minimum error. I know that it is a very inefficient way to solve this problem, and for bigger arrays it is computationally very expensive (it takes ages to get the solution).
That is why I would like to know if there is an efficient way to obtain the solution. I have thought of using optimization techniques to solve it, but I am not sure how could I do it.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to figure out what you're actually trying to achieve. What is the overall goal of your program in terms of abstraction and what purpose are you reproducing the array for?

Comment: @Pokebab it's inspired in The CEO Problem.Imagine 2 senders who can only access one dimension of the array.Sender 1 and 2 see a 1D array (columns and rows respectively). For each input value (0, 1 or 2), they only know the exact column/row separately, but not both.Besides, they can't transmitt the exact column/row of the input, but only an stimation (eg, if the input is in row 1, Sender 1 can only say 'input is in row 0 or 1'). Their mission is to transmitt the information to a receiver who has to decide, based on the independent information received from both, the value of the original input.

Comment: So let me get this straight - You have an array, and two senders. 
You ask the senders, where is the value 2 in this array?
Sender 1 replies "It's in column 0 or 1" and sender 2 replies "its in row 2 or 3".
You will continue to ask the senders where is 1 in this array and they reply. (do you ask them for value 1 again?)
This continues for a certain amount of times, then by deduction, you estimate what the array looks like?

Comment: @Pokebab kind of. The receiver does not know the actual array value. It has to infer the original value from the information received from both senders. So, the scenario is more like the following: the receiver keeps receiving signals from Sender 1 and 2 and from those signals it has to recosntruct as faithfully as possible the original array. Since the information S1 and S2 can transmitt is limited, some error is expected. To solve this I calculated the error for every possible combination. However, this approach is not scalable. Hope you get the whole picture now. Thanks!